# set any subdomain for a given domain in apache in IOS

Tags: apache2, multi-subdomains, ios

I am working in localhost, I've created a domain like this

in /etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1 *.example.com
```

in /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.example.local
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/workspace/example"
    SetEnv ENV_MODE "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then when I try to type any url like : http://something.example.local or http://whatever.example.local, it doesn't work.

before I have a lot of configurations, one for www.example.local, another for anything.example.local, other.example.local, etc... but this is tedious because I can have a lot of subdomains, and I would like to set all in one with a wildcard or something similar.

As I said in the title, I am with OS X El Capitan.

Thanks !